# Google keeps moving my (favourite) contacts to the "other contacts" section in Google Contacts

Tags: google, google-contacts

So, this has been bugging me for a while. A few months ago, I wanted to call up an old friend of mine, but couldn't find his contact anywhere. I just wrote it off as weird bug (maybe user error on my side) and wrote him on Instagram instead. This happend again and again, with different contacts (all of which I had saved on Google for years, even starred contacts).

When I entered the web version of contacts, I realised that they weren't actually being deleted, but rather moved into a section called "other contacts". The little info button on the web version just tells me to check the settings in "my google account" to control how those contacts are managed (very specific).

Moving the contact back into the normal list does not fix the issue. They'll disappear again sooner or later, more often than not even twice a day. This seems to only happen to a certain group of contacts (around 70ish out of 170), with no discernible pattern as far as I am concerned. I already checked the permissions on my phone, nothing out of the ordinary there either. Also exported all contacts, cleaned up the csv, deleted everything in GC and uploaded them again. Same issue persists.

Any help on the issue would be greatly appreciated, because this is driving me insane. Thanks in advance.